# After remove part of data in a text field from a table, why the data is still able to be retrieve?

Tags: mysql

Is there anyone that has this problem before?

I removed part of data in a text type field from a table, for example, the data was like 'adcdefghi', after the action of remove, the data becomes like 'abcd'. However, when I retrieve data from that field, the result is still 'adcdefghi'.

I'm sure that I changed the right database. Is there something I have to do before I retrieve the data?????

Comment: What commands are you using? Are you running these commands from a database access client or from a web page? More information is needed.

Comment: I can see that the data is already changed in the db, just when I retrieve data by using a function, then the removed part comes back again. I'm just wondering how this happened.

Comment: {{{{update alert set message = REPLACE(message,'abcdefghi','abcd');}}}}

Comment: Transact-SQL, you'll need to do a COMMIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Commit** method of the Database object finalizes the persistent form of the database.

```
a. You must assure that you COMMIT the transaction
b. Make sure that the query browser is not in Start a new transaction while your doing transaction in your System.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to do **COMMIT** after change the value.